# Ubuntu 14.04 cannot open nvidia settings/switch between gpus, hybrid graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.04, graphics, hybrid-graphics

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad edge e531 laptop that dual boots windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. Prior to upgrading to 14.04 I was using bumblebee in order to utilize my nvidia gpu (Nvidia GeForce 740M). In 14.04 I read somewhere that it was better to use prime and switch easily between the two graphic cards at any time.

So I tried installing nvidia 331, 337 and all other versions between 331 and 337 that automatically came with prime installed, but I encountered the following problem:

Once the nvidia driver is installed, the laptop starts using the nvidia card exclusively and when I switch back to my Intel card I can no longer open nvidia settings and I can no longer switch back to my nvidia card. This is what I get when I try to launch nvidia settings from the terminal:

```
** Message: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? yes
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried everything (installed prime indicator, tried with different version of nvidia driver), but to no avail. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to find a solution (using the terminal to move between graphic cards, having a GeForce 840M and Ubuntu 14.04).

First of all, I had broken many things in the system, so I decided to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 again (some things were not fixed after removing nvidia packages... so I decided to start from scratch). After having Ubuntu 14.04 completely new, I have added the following repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Then I did the classical `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, and after that, I installed only these 2 packages:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-common
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

The driver for my 840M GPU should be the 337, but I read that probably 331 works in a better way.

So I rebooted and everything seemed to be right. Then, by running

```
prime-select query
```

I saw that it was using nvidia. And nvidia-settings opened correctly. Then I chose from the nvidia-settings to move to Intel. I logged out and when I came back, I was working with intel (check it with `prime-select query`).

And at this point, nvidia-settings stops working and is not able to open. But if I run in a terminal

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

and then I log out, the new session start under nvidia GPU and nvidia-settings is able to open again.

In conclusion, after doing that, now I move from one GPU to the other by typing

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

or

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

and logging out after it. And the nvidia-settings only opens when I'm working under the nvidia GPU.

I hope this will be useful for you... I've tried 331 drivers before, but it had't work. I think for me the important point was to reinstall Ubuntu and to install 331 drivers at the begining.

In addition, I have to say that the first time I move from the Intel to Nvidia, X crashed and asked me about reconfiguring it. I said ok, I rebooted and from that point now I move from intel to nvidia (using the terminal) without problems, but probably you won't have this X crash...

Good luck!

Comment: prime-select is the shizzz!